# If a point $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum $\alpha(A)$ of $A$, how to prove that $\alpha(A)$ consists of the closed interval $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the operator $$(Ax)(t) = tx(t)$$ in $L^2(0,1)$.

I am trying to use the idea that if $0 <\lambda < 1$, then $x_n(t) =\sqrt{n}$ for $\lambda< t< \lambda + (1/n),$ and $x_n(t) = 0$ if $t\notin [\lambda,\lambda + (1/n)]$.

Already I know that a point $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum $\alpha(A)$ of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $H$, a Hilbert space, such that $$\|x_n\|=1,~~~~\lim\limits_{n}\|Ax_n-\lambda x_n\|=0.$$

I am also aware that $L^2(0,1)$ is a Hilbert space with the inner product defined by $$\langle f , g\rangle:= \int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)} d x.$$

How can I show that $\alpha(A)$ consists of the closed interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Hint: Can you write down the inverse explicitly?

Comment: Your sequence does the job to show that $(0,1)\subset\sigma(A)$. Since the spectrum is closed you also have $[0,1]\subset\sigma(A)$. Now $A$ is self adjoint and $\|A\|=1$ so $[-1,1]\supset\sigma(A)$. Further $A$ is positive, so $[0,\infty)\supset\sigma(A)$.